# git find last file modification on all branches?

Tags: search, git

I modified a file, i know exactly which one it was but it turns out i didn't merge it with master. I have no idea what branch I put it in but it was no later then 2 months ago but no sooner then last month

Is there a way I can ask git when the last time i modified a specific file but ask to check every branch instead of just my current?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
git log --all --since="2 months ago" --until="2 weeks ago" -- path/to/file
```

If you also need branch names for a specific commit, use `git branch --contains commit-id`.

Comment: I'll try this out tomorrow when i'm at my seat

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a quick way to do this for a single file across every branch (only git diff between two branches), but I would definitely use git blame and/or git diff to figure out the rest if you wind up having to do this branch by branch.