# In git, what is a way to have the same file appear on multiple branches

Tags: git

## TLDR

I want to have a file `doc/results.drawio` updated in several branch I'm working on regardless of the branch on which I make a change.

**In git, How can I update a given file on multiple branches?**

### Details of why I'm looking for this answer

I'm working with multiple branches to experiment on a possible solution(s) to a problem.

For example, I have a main and three branches that hold different (unrelated) solutions to a problem.   The branches (for this question) are:

```
main
feature/experiment-1
feature/experiment-2
feature/experiment-3
```

I have some documentation in `main` that describes all three experiments and the image file `doc/results.drawio` contains the results of the experiments.

#### The problem

The problem I'm running into is this:

1. I'm working on `feature/experiment-2` and need to update the drawing in `doc/results.drawio`, so I update it (in the branch `feature/experiment-2`) and commit my work.
2. I stop working on the experiment and switch to other work I'm doing and return to this project after a few days or a week.
3. I switch to `feature/experiment-1` and after some testing find I want to update the *shared* (sic not really shared) `doc/results.drawio` but don't realize (because it's been multiple days between tests) that I made a change but forgot to merge *just the one file* `doc/results.drawio` into all of the branches: main, feature/experiment-1, feature/experiment-2, and feature/experiment-3.
4. Later, when I realize I'm missing something that I know I changed, I have to find the branch where I made the change and then recreate the change in the version I'm working on.

**Is there a technique that exists in git to keep a given file the same on multiple branches?**

### Solution

I've looked for solutions on how to fix the problem I've created by finding all versions of a given file on each branch so that I can get the latest one and merge it into my current branch; so this is a work around to my problem.

See https://superuser.com/a/540841/331605

Comment: does [git branch - How to update a file across all branches in a Git repository - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940977/how-to-update-a-file-across-all-branches-in-a-git-repository) answer your question?

Comment: Yes it is close enough.  I thought it might require a script but wasn't sure.  Thank you.